# Select columns containing a certain number of values

Tags: pandas

My dataframe contains the index column (Date) and hundreds of columns.

| Date (index) | Menu1 | Menu2 | Menu3 | Menu4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023_1_1_x | NaN | 5 | 10 | NaN |
| 2023_1_2_x | NaN | 8 | 9 | NaN |
| 2023_1_3_x | NaN | 10 | 8 | NaN |
| 2023_1_1_y | 10 | 5 | NaN | NaN |
| 2023_1_2_y | 11 | 8 | NaN | NaN |
| 2023_1_3_y | 12 | 10 | NaN | NaN |

The Date index contains duplicates. That's why they end with x or y.

The dataframe has hundreds of columns. I need to select the columns like **Menu3** whose index contains x and the values exist for only those x indexes.

Comment: how should look the result? Like `['Menu2', 'Menu3']` ?

Comment: Correct. The result should be a subset containing only the rows whose index contains x.

Comment: "only the rows" - but you were saying about "columns"

Comment: both the columns and their rows. A subset of the original dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by columns ending in _x or not, then check the NA status and ensure only the _x ones have non-NA:

```
out = (df.notna()
         .groupby(df.index.str.endswith('_x'))
         .any()
         .pipe(lambda d: d.columns[d.eq(d.index, axis=0).all()])
         .tolist()
       )
```

Output: `['Menu3']`